# Objects in a switch statment

Tags: java, object, if-statement, switch-statement

How can I use objects in a switch statement?
I am obliged to use objects in my code. I need to know how to compare objects, by using and If statement or a switch statement.

```
    userInput = userLnr.readLine();

        if (userInput !=null) {
            clerk1.username = userInput;

            userInput = userLnr.readLine();
            clerk2.username = userInput;

            userInput = userLnr.readLine();
            clerk3.username = userInput;

            userInput = userLnr.readLine();
            clerk4.username = userInput;

            userInput = userLnr.readLine();
            clerk1.password = userInput;

            userInput = userLnr.readLine();
            clerk2.password = userInput;

            userInput = userLnr.readLine();
            clerk3.password = userInput;

            userInput = userLnr.readLine();
            clerk4.password = userInput;
        }

    System.out.println("Enter username: ");
    String inputUsername = Keyboard.readString();

    System.out.println("Enter password: ");
    String inputPassword = Keyboard.readString();

    switch(inputUsername){
        case clerk1.username:
    }
```

Comment: I assume that this is for a school assignment or something similar. If it's not then this is not how you want to be doing any of this.

Comment: Yes its for a school project.

Comment: Even for a school project this is not how you want to be doing this. More importantly this is not how you *can* do this. While `switch` does work with `Strings` (these days), you need compile time constants for `case`. So `case "johndoe":` will work, but `case clerk1.username:` isn't possible. However it's a bit unclear what you're even attempting to do.

Comment: I knew about the method you said by doing ex. case"johndoe": . But is there any way to compare objects? as I am obliged to use objects in my project

Comment: Well, considering that Java is an object oriented language, it would be hard *not* to use objects. Are you familiar with the `equals()` method?

Comment: Yes I am, but I tried doing - if (inputusername.equals(clerk1.username){}
But it seems that it doesn't work either

Comment: That should work. Seems you maybe doing something else incorrectly.

Comment: I get the error (cannot find symbol - variable clerk1) by doing: if (inputUsername.equals(clerk1.username)){
        }

Comment: I see no declaration of `clerk1` in the code you've posted. Either you're trying to use it outside its scope or you haven't declared it at all.

Comment: See [Please explain the following about the "Cannot find symbol" error:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean).

Comment: Yes I do have clerk1 declared in the Code as shown below:
        User clerk1 = new User();

Comment: Thanks. I found the problem. I was declaring clerk1 in the try{}